# How to align these checkbuttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, ttk

I want to ask, how to align these few checkbuttons in tkinter. I m using ttk.
[image: Checkbuttons, that I want to align to the LEFT]

This is my code

```
button_frame=Frame(main, style='TFrame')
checks_frame=Frame(main, style='TFrame')
output_frame=Frame(main, style='TFrame')
start_button=Button(button_frame, text='START', command=lambda: _thread.start_new_thread(suspend_processes, ()), state=NORMAL, style='TButton')
stop_button=Button(button_frame, text='STOP', command=lambda: restore_all_processes(False, False), state=DISABLED, style='TButton')
restore_button=Button(button_frame, text='RESTORE', command=lambda: restore_all_processes(False, True), style='TButton')
scrollbar=Scrollbar(output_frame)
out=Text(output_frame, state=NORMAL, bg='white', width=50, height=10, spacing3=True, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=('Calibri'), foreground=theme)
strict_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Strict mode (FPS+)', variable=strict, command=switch_strict, style='TCheckbutton')
real_time_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Use real time priority (experimental, sound may lagg, FPS+)', state=NORMAL, command=switch_real_time, variable=real_time)
dis_game_sound_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Disable in game sound (recommended, FPS+)', state=DISABLED, command=switch_dis_game_sound, variable=dis_game_sound)
dis_grass_swaying_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Disable grass swaying (FPS+)', variable=dis_grass_swaying)
dis_per_pixel_point_lighting_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Disable per pixel point lighting (FPS+)', variable=dis_per_pixel_point_lighting)
slow_client_check=Checkbutton(checks_frame, text='Slow Client (max performance for client)', variable=slow_client)

button_frame                      .pack()
start_button                      .pack(side=LEFT)
stop_button                       .pack(side=LEFT)
restore_button                    .pack(side=LEFT)
checks_frame                      .pack(side=LEFT)
dis_per_pixel_point_lighting_check.pack()
dis_grass_swaying_check           .pack()
slow_client_check                 .pack()
strict_check                      .pack()
real_time_check                   .pack()
dis_game_sound_check              .pack()
output_frame                      .pack(side=RIGHT)
out                               .pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scrollbar                         .pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=Y)
```

Please help me. Thanks for any response.

Comment: You've posted a bunch of irrelevant code. Can you please reduce it down to a [mcve]? Also, have you read the documentation for checkbuttons and for pack to see what options are available? The question you asked can be answered by reading available documentation and doing a little experimentation.

Comment: Have a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: Have you considered using the [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) instead of `pack()`?

Comment: You could use .place(x=#, y=#) instead and then you can set exactly where everything goes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to set the *pack* **anchor** attribute on each checkbutton widget. The default anchor is 'center', which is why they are aligned in the center of the container. So here is the fix.

```
dis_per_pixel_point_lighting_check.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
dis_grass_swaying_check           .pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
slow_client_check                 .pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
strict_check                      .pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
real_time_check                   .pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
dis_game_sound_check              .pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
```

Comment: An example would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: I have a multiline text in Checkboxes. Only the last line gets aligned. The first line is still centered. Any idea? I'm on python 3.6.5

Comment: Multi-line checkboxes can have all of their text aligned to the left, right or center (center is the default) by setting the `justify` attribute. To left justify the multiple lines of text, try: `my_checkbutton['justify'] = 'left'`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-align-checkbutton-in-ttk-to-the-left-side

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x350")

# Create a LabelFrame
frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Select the Subjects", padx=20, pady=20)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=10)

# Create four checkbuttons inside the frame
C1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="Mathematics", width=200, anchor="w").pack()

C2 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Physics", width=200, anchor="w").pack()

C3 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Chemistry", width=200, anchor="w").pack()

C4 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Biology", width=200, anchor="w").pack()

root.mainloop()
```