# Python3 Tkinter chckbutton align left multiline-text

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I have a added a good number of checkbuttons using tkinter module in python3. They were aligned center. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291607/3337089) answer and set anchor to left (W)

```
check_box.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)
```

The checkbuttons got aligned to left. But I have a few checkbuttons which contain multiline text. For these checkbuttons, the last lines are aligned left, but not the first lines. How to align the first lines to left as well?

My python version is 3.6.5

Edit1: Adding code

```
notebook = Notebook(root)
tab1 = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab, text="Tab1")
checkbox_var1 = IntVar()
checkbox1 = Checkbutton(tab1, text="line1\nline2", variable=checkbox_var1)
checkbox1.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)

checkbox_var2 = IntVar()
checkbox2 = Checkbutton(tab1, text="line1\nline2", variable=checkbox_var2)
checkbox2.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)

notebook.pack()
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Did you not read the documentation for the Checkbutton class?  There's a `justify=LEFT` option you can provide.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Actually I had tried it, but without `checkbox2.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)`. It didn't align the checkbuttons, so I thought it didn't work. Anyway, thanks again. You can write it as an answer. I'll accept it.